# how to accept fixed length message by spring rest api

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I need to expose one rest API with spring boot that has to accept message content in fixed-length format and, as is(i.e without disturbing fixed-length message content ), need to put into IBM MQ to pass received  fixed-length message to the back end system (IBM mainframe system)via IBM MQ

I would be requesting you to help me with the sample code  for this requirement

Fixed-length format messages, for example:

```
20011228YF2001122814313425 Forest St Marlborough MA017525083828200600
```

Fixed-length format messages use ordinal positions, which are offsets to identify where fields are within the record. There are no field delimiters. An end-of-record delimiter is required, even for the last record.

Comment: "REST" meaning just that you want to submit it over HTTP to Spring Controllers? You're not wanting like JSON messages, correct? But some custom message format instead?

Comment: below is an example of sample  fixed length file content

Comment: 20011228YF2001122814313425 Forest St Marlborough  MA017525083828200600

Comment: my rest controller has to accept the above message format. if any disturbance of content leads to damage entire message. it should be a fixed-length format

Comment: And how is that "string" message to be submitted? Since you're saying REST, I'm assuming HTTP. Are you needing it as a POST body or like a PUT? Is it supposed to be a "form" field?

Comment: It's Post method

Answer (score 0):

As I see this is more into javax.validation.constraints package. In your entity, you do something like

```
public class Market {
    @NotNull
    @Size(max=4)
    private String marketCode;
    // getters/setters
}
```

So when you try to bind values from @RequestBody Market market, it will throw error regarding the length.

Comment: I am receiving the request as below sample format

Comment: 20011228YF2001122814313425 Forest St Marlborough MA017525083828200600

Comment: your validation is not suitable for this use case